# Cannot resolve symbols for imported seekBar view

Tags: android, android-studio

I am brand new to Android development and I'm currently working on my first application.

I added a circular seekBar view to my project but it is not working.

I imported the view from the following link and followed the quick start instructions: https://github.com/feeeei/CircleSeekbar

[image: Preview my seekBar here]

My IDE is Android Studio. I am using Android SDK 23. The issue seems to be with 
an inability to resolve symbols labeled CircularSeekBar_x inside the CircularSeekBar.java file. (Example: CircularSeekBar_circle_x_radius).

See code snippet below.

I appreciate any help with this. Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:** I figured out that the R.styleable.CircularSeekBar_x variables are causing the error because that are not being generated in the R file. The question is why are they not getting generated? Does anyone know where these variables would (or should) be stored?

```
    /**
     * Initialize the CircularSeekBar with the attributes from the XML style.
     * Uses the defaults defined at the top of this file when an attribute is not specified by the user.
     * @param attrArray TypedArray containing the attributes.
     */
    protected void initAttributes(TypedArray attrArray) {
        mCircleXRadius = attrArray.getDimension(R.styleable.CircularSeekBar_circle_x_radius, DEFAULT_CIRCLE_X_RADIUS * DPTOPX_SCALE);
        mCircleYRadius = attrArray.getDimension(R.styleable.CircularSeekBar_circle_y_radius, DEFAULT_CIRCLE_Y_RADIUS * DPTOPX_SCALE);
        mPointerRadius = attrArray.getDimension(R.styleable.CircularSeekBar_pointer_radius, DEFAULT_POINTER_RADIUS * DPTOPX_SCALE);
        mPointerHaloWidth = attrArray.getDimension(R.styleable.CircularSeekBar_pointer_halo_width, DEFAULT_POINTER_HALO_WIDTH * DPTOPX_SCALE);
        mPointerHaloBorderWidth = attrArray.getDimension(R.styleable.CircularSeekBar_pointer_halo_border_width, DEFAULT_POINTER_HALO_BORDER_WIDTH * DPTOPX_SCALE);
        mCircleStrokeWidth = attrArray.getDimension(R.styleable.CircularSeekBar_circle_stroke_width, DEFAULT_CIRCLE_STROKE_WIDTH * DPTOPX_SCALE);

        mPointerColor = attrArray.getColor(R.styleable.CircularSeekBar_pointer_color, DEFAULT_POINTER_COLOR);
        mPointerHaloColor = attrArray.getColor(R.styleable.CircularSeekBar_pointer_halo_color, DEFAULT_POINTER_HALO_COLOR);
        mPointerHaloColorOnTouch = attrArray.getColor(R.styleable.CircularSeekBar_pointer_halo_color_ontouch, DEFAULT_POINTER_HALO_COLOR_ONTOUCH);
        mCircleColor = attrArray.getColor(R.styleable.CircularSeekBar_circle_color, DEFAULT_CIRCLE_COLOR);
        mCircleProgressColor = attrArray.getColor(R.styleable.CircularSeekBar_circle_progress_color, DEFAULT_CIRCLE_PROGRESS_COLOR);
        mCircleFillColor = attrArray.getColor(R.styleable.CircularSeekBar_circle_fill, DEFAULT_CIRCLE_FILL_COLOR);

        mPointerAlpha = Color.alpha(mPointerHaloColor);

        mPointerAlphaOnTouch = attrArray.getInt(R.styleable.CircularSeekBar_pointer_alpha_ontouch, DEFAULT_POINTER_ALPHA_ONTOUCH);
        if (mPointerAlphaOnTouch > 255 || mPointerAlphaOnTouch < 0) {
            mPointerAlphaOnTouch = DEFAULT_POINTER_ALPHA_ONTOUCH;
        }

        mMax = attrArray.getInt(R.styleable.CircularSeekBar_max, DEFAULT_MAX);
        mProgress = attrArray.getInt(R.styleable.CircularSeekBar_progress, DEFAULT_PROGRESS);
        mCustomRadii = attrArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.CircularSeekBar_use_custom_radii, DEFAULT_USE_CUSTOM_RADII);
        mMaintainEqualCircle = attrArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.CircularSeekBar_maintain_equal_circle, DEFAULT_MAINTAIN_EQUAL_CIRCLE);
        mMoveOutsideCircle = attrArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.CircularSeekBar_move_outside_circle, DEFAULT_MOVE_OUTSIDE_CIRCLE);
        lockEnabled = attrArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.CircularSeekBar_lock_enabled, DEFAULT_LOCK_ENABLED);

        // Modulo 360 right now to avoid constant conversion
        mStartAngle = ((360f + (attrArray.getFloat((R.styleable.CircularSeekBar_start_angle), DEFAULT_START_ANGLE) % 360f)) % 360f);
        mEndAngle = ((360f + (attrArray.getFloat((R.styleable.CircularSeekBar_end_angle), DEFAULT_END_ANGLE) % 360f)) % 360f);
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you are seeing??

Comment: In the Android Studio preview, the seekbar does not look correct (see link to picture).

Comment: When I try to run the app in my GenyMotion emulator, the app does not build. I get "cannot resolve symbols" errors for variables labeled CircularSeekBar_x (For example: CircularSeekBar_circle_x_radius).